# Reassemble raid 1 array with mdadm

Tags: partitioning, raid, mdadm

I have a raid array that for some reason, has stopped being assembled. It was called /dev/md0, but now /dev/md0 no longer exists and /proc/mdstat only contains another array I have, not both of them.

However, if I run `sudo mdadm --examine --scan`, both appear

`ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=aee0e79d:1d897c57:b87e879b:7fb3e1d9 name=desktop:1
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=e5c5b859:bdcb97ea:f561d1dc:fabdacef name=desktop:0`

The missing array is /dev/md0, so it apparently exists to a degree but it is not being assembled. How can I reassemble this array without losing the data on the disks in the array?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the metadata on the drive are still there. You can first use 'lsblk' to check if all the Raid member drives for /dev/md0 are still appear in the system, if they do appear, try using 'mdadm -A -s' for automatically assemble the Raid Volume.

If failed, you can try to assemble them by yourself using 'mdadm -A /dev/md0 /dev/XXX /dev/YYY'. /dev/XXX /dev/YYY are the drive that original /dev/md0 using.

After that, you can use 'mdadm -E -s > /etc/mdadm.conf' to create the raid metadata file, system will use the info base on this file to assemble Raid Volumes during reboot.

Stop and Reassembly Raid Volume won't cause data loss.